# I need help switching background images with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, image, loops

I have an unordered list of img url's that are generated with from a custom post type in wordpress.

I have a slider and am using the number of slides to determine which Image url I want as the background for my element.

Sample of generated list:

```
<ul class="tes-image-links">
    <li>http://img-url1</li>
    <li>http://img-url2</li>
    <li>http://img-url3</li>
</ul>
```

Sample of my jQuery

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').find('.cycle-slide').each(function(i){
    if (  $(this).hasClass('cycle-slide-active') ){
        var apimglink = $('.tes-image-links').children('li').eq(i).text();
        $('.ap-testimonial.img-back').css("background" , "'url('"+apimglink+"') !important'" );
    }
});
```

When I use `console.log()` it spits out the right text that is in the `<li>` tag, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: try with `"url('"+apimglink+"') !important"`, Also I think you don't need `important` as `.css()` will add inline style.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it without !important and with important but it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove single quotes and !imprtant from background properties. Also dont forget to wrap your function in a DOM ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cycle-slideshow').find('.cycle-slide').each(function(i){
        if (  $(this).hasClass('cycle-slide-active') ){
        var apimglink = $('.tes-image-links').children('li').eq(i).text();
        $('.ap-testimonial .img-back').css("background" , "url('"+apimglink+"')" );

        }

    });
    })
```

Comment: Hi thank you for responding. I have it wrapped around
    $(window).load(function(){});

I have tried putting in what you gave me but still no luck. When I do a console.log() it spits back the img url corresponding with the slide but it is not being used in the background for ap-testimonial.img-back.

Also when the slide updates and a new slide hasClass('cycle-slide-active') it does not update and I don't receive the new img url in the console, from my console.log(apimglink).

Comment: I dont know what is .ap-testimonial.img-back class? if they are child and parent, a space is needed between them: .ap-testimonial .img-back

Comment: also you have condition which check if element has class "cycle-slide-active". it seems that you have a slideshow which changes after a certain seconds. So you need to call this function on every change instead of only at $(window).load

Comment: It is the same element. It wasn't working so I was trying to be more specific. It has more than one class name. ".ap-testimonial.img-back".

So it should be $(document).on('change', 'cycle-slide', function() {})?
I'll give it a try, but shouldn't it work at least for the first slide since the variable is storing the img url for whichever slide first has .cycle-slide-active?

Comment: if these class names are not used in other elements of page, one class would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The previous code is giving me issues and I could not get it to show the image with `.each()`.

Using a for-loop I was able to get the Section to use the URL as a background based on the slide number:

```
var cycleSlide = $('.cycle-slideshow').find('.cycle-slide');
for (i = 0; i < cycleSlide.length; i++) { 

    if (cycleSlide.eq(i).hasClass('cycle-slide-active')){
        var apimglink = $('.tes-image-links').children('li').eq(i).text();
        apimglink = apimglink.replace("http://localhost", "");
        $('.ap-testimonial').css('background-image', 'url(' + apimglink + ')');
        console.log(apimglink);

    } //End If

}; //End For
```

Thank you all for your help.